# OpenCL: weird kernel behavior

Tags: c, opencl, gpu, gpgpu, amd-processor

So I'm trying to make heads and tails to get a certain piece of code to work in OpenCL.

And since I didn't get the originally intended results I've been trying various ways to figure out what went wrong. So I came up with the code attached below and after successful execution it didn't produce the intended results.

The original vision of this code was to execute a specified number of threads and copy the thread number into an array.

```
Threads: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

However the result that I get.

```
Threads: 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 7 0 0 0 11 0 0 0 15
```

With the results that I'm getting their is a pattern. So every

```
(n % 4)
```

it seems to put a number in my array. I started thinking if for some reason the code is being treated as `int` and converted to `char`.

**OS**: [mac](/questions/tagged/mac)-[osx](/questions/tagged/osx) (Snow Leopard)

```
gcc main.c -o threadsopencl -std=c99 -framework OpenCL



#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenCL/opencl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

#include <stdlib.h>     // warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’
#include <stdio.h>      // error: ‘stderr’ undeclared (first use in this function)

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    /* Retrieve Platforms */

    cl_uint Platforms = 0;

    printf("Checking for OpenCL platforms.\n");

    if (CL_SUCCESS == clGetPlatformIDs ( 0, NULL, &Platforms))
    {
        printf("Found %d platform.\n", Platforms);

        if (Platforms > 0)
        {

            /* Retrieve Platform ID */

            printf("Retrieving OpenCL platform details.\n");

            cl_platform_id *Platform = malloc((sizeof(cl_platform_id) * Platforms));

            clGetPlatformIDs( Platforms, Platform, &Platforms);


            /* Retrieve Devices on Platform */

            cl_uint GPUs = 0;

            printf("Retrieving GPU devices associated with the detected platform.\n");

            clGetDeviceIDs( Platform[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, NULL, &GPUs);

            if (GPUs > 0)
            {

                printf("Found %d GPU device(s).\n", GPUs);

                cl_device_id  *GPU = malloc((sizeof(cl_device_id) * GPUs));

                clGetDeviceIDs( Platform[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, GPUs, GPU, &GPUs);


                cl_uint Error;


                printf("Creating OpenCL context and associating it with the detected GPU device.\n");
                                        //clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &devices[device_no], &pfn_notify, NULL, &_err)
                cl_context GPUcontext = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &GPU[0], 0, NULL, &Error);
                //clCreateContextFromType( NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, NULL, NULL, &Error);

                if (Error != CL_SUCCESS)
                {
                    printf("Failed to create an OpenCL context!\n");
                    return 1;
                }


                const char *program_source[] = {
                    "__kernel void NumberOfThreads( __global uchar *thread)\n",
                    "{\n",
                    "uchar id = convert_uchar(get_global_id(0));\n",
                    "thread[id] = id;\n",
                    "}\n"
                };


                printf("Creating a program for execution on the device.\n");

                cl_program AES = clCreateProgramWithSource( GPUcontext, sizeof(program_source)/sizeof(*program_source), program_source, NULL, &Error);

                if (Error != CL_SUCCESS)
                {
                    printf("Failed to create a program from source!\n");
                    return 1;
                }


                printf("Attempting compilation!\n");

                if (clBuildProgram( AES, GPUs, &GPU[0], "", NULL, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS) {
                    printf("Program compilation failed!\n");

                    char buffer[10240];

                    clGetProgramBuildInfo( AES, GPU[0], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), buffer, NULL);

                    fprintf(stderr, "CL Compilation failed:\n%s", buffer);
                    exit(2); // abort();
                }

                /* Since OpenCL compilation failed is due to incomplete code work */


                printf("Allocating space for the data to be executed within the context.\n");

                cl_mem Threads = clCreateBuffer( GPUcontext, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, 16*sizeof(char), NULL, &Error);

                if (Error != CL_SUCCESS)
                {
                    printf("Failed to allocate buffer for State Matrix!\n");
                    return 1;
                }


                printf("Creating an OpenCL kernel!\n");

                cl_kernel ThreadsKernel = clCreateKernel( AES, "NumberOfThreads", &Error);
                clSetKernelArg( ThreadsKernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &Threads);


                if (Error != CL_SUCCESS)
                {
                    printf("Failed to create kernel object!\n");
                    return 1;
                }


                printf("Setting up an execution queue.\n");

                cl_command_queue ExecutionQueue = clCreateCommandQueue( GPUcontext, GPU[0], 0, &Error);

                if (Error != CL_SUCCESS)
                {
                    printf("Failed to create command queue!\n");
                    return 1;
                }


                printf("Commencing with kernel execution!\n");

                cl_event ExecutionComplete;

                size_t global_work_size[1] = { 16 };

                if (clEnqueueNDRangeKernel( ExecutionQueue, ThreadsKernel, 1, NULL, global_work_size, NULL, 0, NULL, &ExecutionComplete) != CL_SUCCESS)
                {
                    //printf("Failed to execute kernel! Error %d\n", (unsigned int)Error);

                    switch(Error)
                    {
                        case CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE:
                        printf("CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE\n");
                        break;
                        case CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE:
                        printf("CL_INVALID_COMMAND_QUEUE\n");
                        break;
                        case CL_INVALID_KERNEL:
                        printf("CL_INVALID_KERNEL\n");
                        break;
                        case CL_INVALID_CONTEXT:
                        printf("CL_INVALID_CONTEXT\n");
                        break;
                        case CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS:
                        printf("CL_INVALID_KERNEL_ARGS\n");
                        break;
                        case CL_INVALID_WORK_DIMENSION:
                        printf("CL_INVALID_WORK_DIMENSION\n");
                        break;
                        case CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE:
                        printf("CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_WORK_SIZE\n");
                        break;
                        case CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE:
                        printf("CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE\n");
                        break;
                        case CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE:
                        printf("CL_INVALID_WORK_ITEM_SIZE\n");
                        break;
                        case CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_OFFSET:
                        printf("CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_OFFSET\n");
                        break;
                        case CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES:
                        printf("CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES\n");
                        break;
                        case CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE:
                        printf("CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE\n");
                        break;
                        case CL_INVALID_EVENT_WAIT_LIST:
                        printf("CL_INVALID_EVENT_WAIT_LIST\n");
                        break;
                        case CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY:
                        printf("CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY\n");
                        break;
                        default:
                        printf("Failed to execute kernel! %u\n", (unsigned int)Error);
                    }

                    return 1;
                }
                clWaitForEvents( 1, &ExecutionComplete);
                clReleaseEvent( ExecutionComplete);


                printf("ThreadValue:");
                for ( char Loop = 0; Loop < 16; Loop++)
                {
                    unsigned char ThreadValue = 0;

                    if (clEnqueueReadBuffer( ExecutionQueue, Threads, CL_TRUE, Loop, 1, &ThreadValue, 0, NULL, NULL) != CL_SUCCESS)
                    {
                        printf("Failed to copy data back from Device to Host!\n");
                        return 1;
                    }

                    printf(" %d", ThreadValue);
                }

                printf("\n");

                printf("Freeing memory and exiting!\n");


                clReleaseMemObject(Threads);

                clReleaseKernel(ThreadsKernel);
                clReleaseProgram(AES);
                clReleaseContext(GPUcontext);


            }

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it seems you are doing tid * tid inside kernel, so expected result should be 0,1,3,9 ... On my AMD machine I am getting this result.

Comment: get_global_id(0) -> retrieves thread number, then it's converted to unsigned char, which is then selected in the thread array (originally passed along the argument during kernel call) which then stores the thread number * multiplied by itself.

Comment: Fixed the (id * id). But even when I ran the code, it printed 0 0 0 9 0 0 0 49 0 0 0 121 0 0 0 225. So 3 bytes of NULL value and then the multiplication operation from the kernel function. The code should've exhibited the following results: 0 1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 91 100 121 144 169 196 225

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using OpenCL 1.0? That doesn't allow writes to char* by default. 1.0 only supports writes into ints.

You need 1.1 or the extension http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_byte_addressable_store.html

You can try adding

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_byte_addressable_store : enable
```

At the start of your kernel.